# PHP MySQL query returns wrong character

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, unicode

I have a database with names.
I have a PHP MySQL query that fetches names form that database.
These names include characters like `ž, š, đ, č, ć, etc.`

But when I run the Website these characters are displayed as this `�`

I have a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my header and the database was created with `utf8_general_ci`, and I also tried `utf8_unicode_ci` as well.

What can I do ?

EDIT: If I use utf8_encode for the echo it returns the name without the characters

Comment: when you `echo` the data, use `utf8_encode()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Just try charset="utf-8"

Answer (score 1):

You should set NAMES character set:

```
mysqli_query ($connection, "SET NAMES 'UTF-8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysqli_set_charset ($connection, "utf8");
```

before executing query ...

Answer (score 0):

I have these lines in my /etc/my.cnf under mysqld section

```
 [mysqld]
 init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
 init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
 default-character-set=utf8
 character-set-server = utf8
 collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

this will become a global setting if all your scripts need it

Answer (score 0):

set CHARSET=utf8 in your database

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**PHP file** add the following at the top of your code

```
<?php

   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

**Connect MYSQL** (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Note: **Make sure your PHP script file is saved in UTF8**